# How do I declare a vector of sparse matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

To declare a vector of dense matrix in Eigen I am using the following format

```
std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> AMAT(idx, Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(1000,1000));
```

where idx is the vector size. Is there an equivalent declaration to define a sparse matrix? I am currently declaring a sparse matrix as

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>  BMAT(1000,1000);
```

It will be more efficient for to me define a vector of such matrix instead of declaring separate sparse matrix for each index. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could do something like `std::vector<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> BMATvec(idx, BMAT);`. Is that sufficient for you?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the size of the matrix can be different for each index. So the correct definition of the dense matrix would be ```std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> AMAT(idx, Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(x,x));``` where x can be different for each idx

Comment: Following declaration seems to work. ```std::vector<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> BMAT(idx, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> (x,x));```. Thanks for your help JHBonarius

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you should use a generator. The current vector constructor you are using is filling all the items with copied of the same initializer object. You probaly have to resize them all after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing you want the matrices in the vector to have differen sizes, you should probably not use that initialization constructor for `std::vector`.

Instead just build-up the vector element by element:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    auto sizes = { 100, 200, 300 };

    std::vector<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> BMATvec;
    BMATvec.reserve(sizes.size());

    std::transform(cbegin(sizes), cend(sizes), back_inserter(BMATvec),
        [](auto size) { return Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>(size,size);});
}
```